# If a proposition can be proved nonconstructively, does a constructive version of it also hold?

Tags: logic, soft-question, constructive-mathematics

In this question, I define as follows.

- A sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ **constructively converges** to $a$ if there is a function $N:(0, \infty)\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \varepsilon>0, \forall n>N(\varepsilon), |a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ holds.
- A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is **constructively continuous** if there is a function $\delta:\mathbb{R}\times (0, \infty)\to(0,\infty)$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \forall \varepsilon >0, \forall y\in\mathbb{R}, (|x-y|<\delta(x, \varepsilon)\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon)$.

(Added later: In the above, it turned out that "function" should be replaced by "computable function". )

Similarly, “constructively uniformly continuous”, “constructively differentiable”, “constructively integrable”, etc… can be defined. To do that, we rephrase the existential quantifier as the existence of a function.

**Theorem** If $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ constructively converges to $a$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is constructively continuous, then $\{f(a_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ constructively converges to $f(a)$.

The above can be said to be a ”constitutive version” of the following.

**Theorem** If $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $\{f(a_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f(a)$.

In general, theorem X is the **constructive version** of theorem Y, if all the terms in Y are rephrased as “constructive~” in X.

Is there a theorem that says, "If a theorem holds, then its constructive version holds," or something similar?

We do not assume the axiom of choice here.

Comment: You haven’t defined “function”. If you use the standard definition, then the axiom of choice guarantees your claim. But this is also a far cry from what people mean by “constructive”.

Comment: @ZhenLin “function” is defined in the standard way. What if we don’t assume the axiom of choice? I don’t know more appropriate name for those concepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Zhen Lin has mentioned in the comments, as written your notion of "constructive ______" agrees with the usual version (which you would likely call "nonconstructive ______"). This is basically because functions, as we usually define them, *don't have to be "definable"* in any sense. So the fact that, "nonconstructively" we have a witness to $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ mean we can simply define a function to be a (choice of) witness!

However, all of this changes if you ask for these functions to be "[Computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory)" (in the sense that it's represented by some computer program) then your definitions *do* become more in line with what someone might call "constructively continuous", etc. This is almost surely what you meant anyways, since the class of functions that a program can compute are a good analogue for the class of functions which you can actually "write down and work with". I'll use the more standard terminology of "computably continuous" instead of "constructively", going forwards, and I'll answer your question in the case that we want all of our witnesses to be computable.

Once you do this, there *are* theorems that say "computably uniformly continuous" implies "computably continuous" in your sense. And in fact, as you suspect, there are "metatheorems" saying that many theorems automatically have a "computable" analogue. As long as your reasoning is **constructive** (by which I mean you don't use the [law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) or the axiom of choice -- though some weak variants like [countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) are allowed) then it holds in the "[effective topos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_topos)". This is an alternate universe where *everything* has a computable witness (unless you specify that it doesn't), and your constructions turn preexisting computable witnesses into new computable witnesses. Working in the effective topos lets you handle this plumbing automatically, so that you're guaranteed that your theorems always end up with computable content!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 2):

I will assume your question has nothing to do with [constructive mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_%28philosophy_of_mathematics%29) as it is usually defined. Your definition of "constructively converges" is practically useless in this context (although perhaps your definition of "constructively continuous" does have some uses).

It turns out that even without the axiom of choice, your notions of constructive convergence and continuity are equivalent to their ordinary versions. To see this, note that your definitions clearly imply the ordinary versions. To go the other way, we begin by discussing "constructive convergence".

Suppose $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$. Define $N(\epsilon)$ to be the smallest $j$ such that for all $n > j$, $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ (at least one $j$ exists by the definition of $\lim$). This shows that $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ constructively converges to $a$.

Similarly, suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Fix a surjection $q : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$, so that $\mathbb{Q} = \{q_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Suppose we have some $x$ and $\epsilon$. Then take some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, if $|y - x| < \delta$ then $|f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. Note that any $\delta' \in (0, \delta)$ satisfies exactly the same property. And note there exists a rational number in $(0, \delta)$ by the Archimedean property and the fact that $\delta > 0$, which can be written as $q_n$ for some $n$. So there exists some $n$ such that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}(|y - x| < q_n \implies |f(y) - f(x) < \epsilon)$. Take the smallest such $n$, and let $\delta(x, y) = q_n$. Then $f$ is constructively continuous.

Comment: +1.  In the last paragraph, you could avoid the enumeration of the rationals by taking $\delta$ to be $1/n$ for the first $n$ that works.